# Calculation of mean energy value of CMB photons for recombination

Tags: plasma-physics, cosmic-microwave-background, ionization-energy

I am interested in the calculation of the mean energy value of CMB (Cosmic Microwave Background) photons from which the recombination is performed.

The subject on French Wikipedia says:

> *"Intuitively, one might say that recombination occurs when energy average of photons is of the order of the ionization energy of hydrogen, 13.6 eV, or about 150 000 Kelvin. In practice, this estimate is incorrect, because the universe is a system that has a large number of photons by the atomic nucleus (of the order of one proton for one billion photons). Therefore, what matters is that the energy of a billionth of the most energetic photons is of the order of the ionization energy of the hydrogen atom. This occurs when the average energy of the "whole" of the photons is less than 13.6 eV.*
>
> *Taking $x_{e}$ the ratio of the abundance of free electrons to the total abundance of hydrogen (both neutral and ionized), i.e :
> $x_{e}=\dfrac{n_{e}}{n_{p}+n_{H}}$
> with $n_{e}$ the number density of free electrons, $n_{H}$ that of atomic hydrogen and $n_{p}$ that of ionized hydrogen (i.e. protons). Saha equation yields :
> $\dfrac{x_{e}^{2}}{1-x_{e}}=\dfrac{5.8\,10^{21}}{\Omega_{b}h^{2}\,T^{3/2}}\,exp\big(\dfrac{-1.58\,10^{5}}{T}\big)$
> Then, recombination is done when average energy value of photons equals to **0.3 eV**, so a temperature of 3000 K.
> "*

I would like to find a demonstration which explains that the energy of a billionth of the most energetic photons must be of the order of the ionization energy of the hydrogen atom (13.6 eV).

Why do the billionth of the most energetic photons has to be equal to 13.6 eV ?

To formulate a demonstration, I would like to start from a probability density function ( Maybe Bose-Einstein distribution for photons) and/or Saha equation.

I am making confusions between the probability of ionisation of a hydrogen atom and this ratio of 1 billion-th, and moreover why all occurs suddenly at an energy of 0.3eV for the plasma.

This process occurs very fast, doesn't it ? I am surprised by this very quick transition "all ionised => all recombined" : I don't realize at which point this threshold in energy makes change everything, i.e the high rate of recombined atoms suddenly.

It seems to be an easy issue but I want to clarify it with a mathematical point of view.

**UPDATE:** Is it possible to have a summary of all the key points on the process of recombination ?, especially the moment when 1 billionth photon have an energy lower than 13.6 eV and all the consequence on recombination.

It seems to be difficult to have a mathematical prove (I don't speak about Saha formula) or a plot representing ionization vs redshift or ionization vs cosmic time.

I think it is more an intuitive explanation (maybe we may explain by cumulative function and not directly with a probability density function (PDF)).

Comment: Shouldn't one rather ask for the mean free path being on the order of the size of the entire visible universe?

Comment: I am unclear whether you don't understand the Saha equation or you don't believe that 1 billionth of the photons have energy greater than 13.6 eV when $T= 3000$ K? BTW At 3000 K, I think the average photon energy is $2.7 kT = 0.7$ eV.

Comment: @ProfRob . Yes, actually, this is the ambiguity that I have difficulties to understand fully : this stuff of 1 billionth of the photons having an energy equal to 0.3eV which have such consequences of the rest of the plasma and make start the recombination. Could you illustrate it with a probability function or another mathematical probability or statistical tool to prove it, this would be great. Maybe a function of temperature or ionisation rate as a function of time (or redshift) would be welcome :

Comment: I have to understand also this process by taking into account the cosmic time, that is to say, how the plasma ionisation evolves to clarify my ignorance. thanks

Comment: I still don't follow. There are a billion times as many photons as protons. If one in a billion photons  has an energy greater than 13.6 eV then (roughly speaking) the hydrogen will be ionised. The argument has nothing to do with cosmic time, other than that the temperature changes with time and thus so does the ionisation fraction - according to the Saha equation. It seems you want a textbook that describes recombination and the CMB.

Comment: @ProfRob .When I talk about a dependence of cosmic time, I mean a dependence in redshift. By chance, have you got a plot representing the ionisation as a function of redshift (optionnaly with an analytical function) ? , that is to say, implicitly as function of time (I agree this is very early times)

Comment: @ProfRob . My bounty expires soon, could you do please a summarize of all our  discussion in an answer and if possible ? ,for example by adding some simple and basic equations that allow to grasp this subtility about the threshold of 1 billionth photons with an energy of 13.6 eV, this would be fine. Regards